# How to use function argument in a mapping?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

Let's take a look at the example below.

```
function! Print (text)
    echo a:text
endfunction

function! Mapping_test (parameter)
    nnoremap m1 :call Print (a:parameter)<CR>
    nnoremap m2 :call Print ("hello")<CR>
    execute 'nnoremap m3 :call Print ("' . a:parameter . '")<CR>'
    execute 'command! -nargs=0 MTest :call Print ("' . a:parameter . '")'
endfunction

call Mapping_test ("hello world")
```

*m1* mapping produces two errors:

```
E121: Undefined variable: a:parameter                                                                                                                                                                                                               
E116: Invalid arguments for function Print
```

*m2* and *m3* work fine. So calling function with string literal is fine, using execute is also ok, but why *m1* does not work?

Basically, I could take *m3* and be happy, but if I change argument of *Mapping_test()* from string literal to an array then *m3* does not work either.

```
call Mapping_test (["hello world"])
```

produces

```
E730: Using a List as a String
```

I even tried to use command, but result is the same, when passing List as *a:parameter*, error occurs.

So, is there any possible way I can pass argument (here *a:parameter*) to a function call (in a mapping) which type is not a String?

Answer (score 1):

Mappings *always* execute in the global context. That is, they don't "remember" that they were defined inside a function, so they can't access `a:` variables directly.

As for the `E730: Using a List as a String` error, you can try using `type()` and `join()`:

```
function! Mapping_test (parameter)
    nnoremap m1 :call Print (a:parameter)<CR>
    nnoremap m2 :call Print ("hello")<CR>
    execute 'nnoremap m3 :call Print ("' . (type(a:parameter) == type([]) ? join(a:parameter, '') : a:parameter) . '")<CR>'
    execute 'command! -nargs=0 MTest :call Print ("' . (type(a:parameter) == type([]) ? join(a:parameter, '') : a:parameter) . '")'
endfunction
```

Comment: and probably don't forget to escape all the stuff inside `parameter` so it doesn't get interpreted by `:map`, unless you want that!

Comment: I thought about converting it to string in the first place, but supposed it is a workaround solution. Seems to be the one for now.

Comment: Basically since you're using `:execute` it requires a string argument, and you were trying to drop in a non-string type. Depending on what you're really trying to do you can get around it, but I wanted to keep my answer simple.